# Set Dropout to be non-zero in Vision Transformer model

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model, vision, dropout, overfitting-underfitting

I am using a Vision Transformer model to do image classification. I am importing
`model_ft = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/deit:main', 'deit_base_patch16_224', pretrained=True)`

Once the model is loaded I print the model to see the different layers and I get :

```
(patch_embed): PatchEmbed(
(proj): Conv2d(3, 768, kernel_size=(16, 16), stride=(16, 16))
(norm): Identity()
)
(pos_drop): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=True)
(blocks): Sequential(
(0): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(1): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(2): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(3): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(4): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(5): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(6): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(7): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(8): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(9): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(10): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
(11): Block(
(norm1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(attn): Attention(
(qkv): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2304, bias=True)
(attn_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
(proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
(proj_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
(drop_path): Identity()
(norm2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(mlp): Mlp(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
(act): GELU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
(drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
)
)
)
(norm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
(pre_logits): Identity()
(head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2, bias=True)
```

**I want to set dropout to be 0.5 in all the different layers. Starting from the first layer when I do : `model_ft._modules["pos_drop"] = nn.Dropout(0.5, inplace=True)`, it works for the first instance of the dropout but when I want to do the same thing for the second dropout and I try `model_ft._modules["blocks"].attn.proj_drop = nn.Dropout(0.5, inplace=True)`, it throws an error.

The real problem is that I don’t know how to access the dropout layers in the network and set them all to non-zero values. I need to know how to index the different layers which have Dropout to option and set them to non-zero values.

I would be very thankful to you if you could help me with how to access the different layers of the model and set dropout to be true in all of them.**

Answer (score 0):

You can see that it's an nn.Sequential object, so you can access those quite easily. If we define a model as:

```
class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(model,self).__init__()
        s = [nn.Dropout(0),nn.Linear(2,10),nn.Linear(10,23),nn.Dropout(0.2)]
        self.s = nn.Sequential(*s)

m = model()
```

Which gives us a model like this:

```
model(
  (s): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0, inplace=False)
    (1): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=10, bias=True)
    (2): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=23, bias=True)
    (3): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
  )
)
```

To access the two dropout layers it's as easy as indexing the sequential object (note you don't have to create a new layer, you can just modify the probability directly):

```
m.s[0].p = 0.2
m.s[3].p = 0.9
```

Which changes the model to:

```
model(
  (s): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
    (1): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=10, bias=True)
    (2): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=23, bias=True)
    (3): Dropout(p=0.9, inplace=False)
  )
)
```

### EDIT

However, if you just want to set every dropout to 0.5, this is the easiest way:

```
for name, layer in m.named_modules():
    if isinstance(layer, nn.Dropout):
         layer.p = 0.5
```

Which provides the desired output, too:

```
model(
  (s): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=False)
    (1): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=10, bias=True)
    (2): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=23, bias=True)
    (3): Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=False)
  )
)
```